# Xamarin Push Notifications Build Error

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I am implementing push notifications within an application using the Azure Messaging component from `Xamarin` - `iOS` only.

- I have been able to successfully build, deploy to a device, and test
  locally.
- The component is installed using the Nuget package for the component.
  However, when I check the changes into source control and try to
  build on our build server

I receive the following error message:

> MTOUCH: error MT1304: The embedded framework
>   'WindowsAzureMessaging.framework' in
>   /Users/Clinician/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/b535d319c25da2ee/Frameworks
>   /packages/Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS.1.2.5.2/lib/Xamarin.iOS10/Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.iOS.dll
>   is invalid: it does not contain an Info.plist.

I haven't been able to find a lot of information about the `MT1304` error.

Has anyone else encountered this or have any suggestions on how to resolve?